# Expected value of product of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If I have two dependent random variables (RVs) $X$ and $Y$ where $X$ is a Gaussian RV with mean $0$ and known variance. Is there a way to lower bound the quantity $ \mathbb{E}[X Y]$?

Comment: Are they independent?  Or jointly gaussian?  You could obtain bounds from the fact that their correlation coefficient $\rho$ must obey $-1\le\rho\le1$.

Comment: Constant variance ???

Comment: Without further assumptions, there is no reason to believe that $\mathbb E[XY]$ even exists.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathbb{E}[X]=0,$ we have $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{Cov}(X,Y).$ Now, it follows from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that $$ \left| \mathbb{Cov} (X, Y) \right | \le \sqrt{\mathbb{Var}[X]\mathbb{Var}[Y]},$$ which gives the lower bound $$ \mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{Cov} (X, Y) \ge - \sqrt{\mathbb{Var}[X]\mathbb{Var}[Y]}.$$ Note that here equality holds when $Y= aX$ for some $a<0.$